# What would be Djnago's url pattern to match and fetch out a url (coming appended to site's domain as a GET request)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

Suppose my site's domain is mysite.com , now whenever a request comes in this form : mysite.com/https://stackoverflow.com :I want to fetch out this url "https://stackoverflow.com" and send it to the corresponding view.

I have tried this pattern :

url(r'^(?P<preurl>http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)$',prepend_view)

regex of which matches the incoming appended url and assigns variable preurl the value "https://stackoverflow.com", which I access in corresponding view function .

This works fine for above example but my url pattern is failing in case of some exceptional urls..
Please suggest a robust url pattern by taking into consideration all exceptional urls too, like the following:

```
 ftp://ftp.is.co.za/rfc/rfc1808.txt

  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt

  ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one

  mailto:John.Doe@example.com

  news:comp.infosystems.www.servers.unix

  tel:+1-816-555-1212

  telnet://192.0.2.16:80/

  urn:oasis:names:specification:docbook:dtd:xml:4.1.2
```

That is, if a request comes like : 
mysite.com/ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one

I should be able to get the value "ldap://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one" in variable preurl

Comment: Please read your question and explain your problem a bit more efficiently. And please do edit the title of the question. For not being careful of how to ask useful questions, I was blocked from asking questions by StackOverflow. Please don't make the same mistake I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make this type of complex url pattern, First, make a URL pattern that matches everything.

```
url(r'^.*/$', views.fast_track_service, name='fast_track'),
```

and append it to the end in urlpatterns in your urls.py then in your view, Use request object, So You can get the full path of get request with this method,

```
fast_track_url = request.get_full_path()[1:]
```

and then once you got the url try validating that with URLValidator like this.

```
if not 'http://' in fast_track_url and not 'https://' in fast_track_url:
        fast_track_url = 'http://' + fast_track_url
url_validate = URLValidator()
try:
    url_validate(fast_track_url)
except:
    raise Http404
```

If you want to validate other complicated URL like mailto etc, then you can write your own validator.